# Spark best practice for loading schema

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm working with `Spark` in some structured streaming projects and more often than not I need to specify the schema for the data that I process. The schema is often pretty complex so I usually infer it from a sample file and save it in a variable; then I use that variable when I start the streaming process.

**This is the code I wrote**:

```
staticDF = spark.read.json("/path/to/file/sample.json", multiLine=True)
mySchema = staticDF.schema

streamedData = spark\
    .readStream\
    .json(origin, schema=mySchema, allowUnquotedFieldNames=True, multiLine=True)
```

This means that every time that I start my application I have to process a JSON file, create a data frame, and get the schema from it.

I wanted to know if there is a better / more efficient way to do that, perhaps saving the schema in a file so that can be used later. I use python 2.7 and pyspark-3.0.0

Thanks :)

Comment: the schema is complex, but is it changing ? you can save your schema as a json, and read it directly form this json file as a param. it is probably faster than reading and infering a json file with spark. But that means you have to generate a schema file for each process.

Comment: @Steven it doesn't change within the scope of a project so I could do that, I just don't know if it is better to save it as a JSON file or in another format (for example .pickle)

Comment: @MarcoBorinato well, json is human readable, and the file will only be few kb ... therefore, no need to serialise it in pickle format.